# Eclipse plugin access Preferences from ViewPart

Tags: view, eclipse-plugin, preferences

I have a view in a perspective which got a Action in the toolbar. This action opens a PreferenceDialog. So the preferences in this Dialog are binded to the view which opens it. I Chose this way because the user can open serval numbers of this view with different content and each view has its preferences.

how can i Access this preferences in the ViewPart?
I tried it like this

```java
IPreferenceStore preferenceStore = Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
```

But Eclipse tells me this:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The method getDefault() is undefined for the type Activator
- Discouraged access: The type Activator is not accessible due to restriction on required library 
 C:\Users\xxx\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.5.100.v20130422-1538.jar
```

what i am doing in my PreferencePage class:

```java
public class PaketFilterPreferencePage extends PreferencePage {

public static final int ALL_PACKETS_SELECTED = 1;
public static final int FILTER_DECODER = 2;
public static final int ALL_DECODER = 0;
public static final String PKFILTER_PREF = "PaketFilterDecoderPref";
public static final String PKFILTER_NODE = "PaketFilterDecoderNode";
...
private void initButtons(){
    IPreferenceStore preferenceStore = getPreferenceStore();
    int pref = preferenceStore.getInt(PKFILTER_PREF);
    if(pref==ALL_PACKETS_SELECTED){
        selectAllPacketsButton.setSelection(true);
        ctv.getTable().setEnabled(false);
        if(selectAllDecoderButton!=null){
            selectAllDecoderButton.setEnabled(false);
            unselectAllButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    else
        selectFilterButton.setSelection(true);
}

@Override
protected void performDefaults() {
    IPreferenceStore preferenceStore = getPreferenceStore();
    preferenceStore.setValue(PKFILTER_PREF, ALL_DECODER);
    initButtons();

}

@Override
public boolean performOk() {
    IPreferenceStore preferenceStore = getPreferenceStore();
    if(selectAllPacketsButton.getSelection())
        preferenceStore.setValue(PKFILTER_PREF, ALL_PACKETS_SELECTED);
    else if(decoderNamesCurrentCopy.equals(decoderNamesAll))
        preferenceStore.setValue(PKFILTER_PREF, ALL_DECODER);
    else
        preferenceStore.setValue(PKFILTER_PREF, FILTER_DECODER);
    return true;
}
}
```

calling

```
setPreferenceStore(Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
```

in the constructor of my PreferencePage gives me a null pointer. I added this line to my manifest

```
Bundle-Activator: xxx.Activator
```

I also added the extension org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences and connected it to this class:

```
 public class AbstractPreferenceInit extends
    AbstractPreferenceInitializer {

public AbstractPreferenceInit() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void initializeDefaultPreferences() {
    IEclipsePreferences node = DefaultScope.INSTANCE.getNode(PaketFilterPreferencePage.PKFILTER_NODE);
    node.putBoolean(PaketFilterPreferencePage.PKFILTER_ALL_PACKETS_RADIO, false);
    node.putInt(PaketFilterPreferencePage.PKFILTER_STATUS, PaketFilterPreferencePage.ALL_DECODER);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the activator for your plugin **not** the preference plugin. If your activator extends `AbstractUIPlugin` it will have a `getPreferenceStore()` method.

Your preference page needs to call

```java
setPreferenceStore(Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
```

during initialization (normally in the constructor).

You probably also want to use the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences` extension point to define a preferences initializer to ensure the preferences always have a value.

Update:
Example activator

```java
public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin {
private static Activator plugin;

public Activator() {
}

@Override
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    super.start(context);
    plugin = this;
}

@Override
public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    plugin = null;
    super.stop(context);
}

public static Activator getDefault() {
    return plugin;
}
}
```

Comment: So i created the class `public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin`. how should the implementation of `getDefault` look like? All examples that i have found dont Show concrete implemenation.

Comment: You normally specify the Activator when you create the plugin and Eclipse writes the code for you. If you create it you must specify the class in the `Bundle-Activator` in the MANIFEST.MF (specify in the Overview section of the manifest.mf/plugin.xml editor). Added an example of the basic activator code to the answer.

Comment: updated the opener and changed the Activator like you suggested

Comment: `initializeDefaultPreferences()`and `start(BundleContext context)`from `Activator` class never get called.

Comment: Check `Activate this plug-in when one of its classes is loaded` in the overview section of the manifest.mf editor. The preference initializer should be called when the preference store is referenced.

Comment: thanks you realy helped me out. there is only one problem left. how can i listen to changes of a node page? there is a possibility over `Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore().addPropertyChangeListener`. but how does that work when i have more than one node. is the `performOK()` Method called for every node even if there where no changes and so for every Preference value the listener is called?

Comment: The preference page performOK is called once when the OK button is pressed. The property change event has the id of the changed property in the event.